# Trying to display Dialogue box in flutter code shows no error but the dialogue box does not show

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, google-apps

I am making a simple Notification app for college I have added a floating button to the bottom navigation bar which should display a dialogue box where I can enter the text to be sent but Dialogue box does not show up when I press the floatingActionbutton i have added a function to onpressed but when I run the code nothing happens the code does not show any kind of error it just does not work I have added the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(notification());
}

class notification extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _notificationState createState() => _notificationState();
}

class _notificationState extends State<notification> {

    Future<bool> addDialog(BuildContext context)async{
      return showDialog(
        context:context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context){

          return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Add Data',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),),
              content: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter the notification'),
                    onChanged: (value){

                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),

              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text('Send'))
              ],
          );

        }
      );
    }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text('Notifications.',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.black),),
         elevation: 0.0,
         backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
       ),
       bottomNavigationBar: Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
         children: <Widget>[
            Container(
             child: FloatingActionButton.extended(onPressed: (){
               addDialog(context);
             },
            icon:Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.black,),
            label: Text('Add',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[600],

            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
            )
         ],
       ),

       body: Center(
         child: Container(

         ),
       )

     ),
    );
  }
}[enter image description here][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "MaterialApp".

```
runApp(MaterialApp(home: notification()));
```